# interface for private network not created when switching from v1 config to v2

Tags: vagrant

in my v1 vagrant config I declared the networking like this.

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "10.11.12.13", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
```

Now I switched to v2 and tried the following versions:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   #1
   #vb.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.13", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
   #2
   #vb.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.13"
   #3
   #vb.network :hostonly, ip: "10.11.12.13", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
   #4
   vb.network :hostonly, ip: "10.11.12.13", netmask: "255.255.0.0"
end
```

But the Result is allways the same: the second networkinterface inside the Ubuntu Precise 64 is not created, so network connections fail. anyone knows a solution different than creating the interface manualy?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you uncomment the items you want? Past the full `Vagrantfile` being used if possible. The networking works fine here v1.2.7.

Comment: the solution is described below. networkconfig has got to be put outsite the provider block.

Comment: Didn't notice that the network config is inside a config.vm.provider block -_-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network configuration should be put outside of the provider block:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.13"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
...
end
```